# Through NMEA data, how to get four satellite states: not in use, receiving, searching, and in use?

Tags: gps, android-gps, gpsd, gps-time, android-gnss

In GPS, through NMEA data, how to get four satellite states: not in use, receiving, searching, and in use? Is it through the SNR value in GSV?

What is the SNR value in GSV